# My jQuery click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

`enter code here`My jQuery click function is not working.
Following is the script that I am trying to run when the id"skills" is clicked.
If I won't wrap the whole function in the `$(document).ready and $("#skills").click` then the function runs alright when the document loads

```
$(document).on('click', 'skills', function() { 


var gaugeConfig = { "canvasHolderId": "HTML", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#2ECC71", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "7.5"}
var gaugeConfig1 = { "canvasHolderId": "CSS", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#2ECC71", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "6.5"}
var gaugeConfig2 = { "canvasHolderId": "JS", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#27AE60", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "7"}
var gaugeConfig3 = { "canvasHolderId": "JQ", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#F1C40F", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "7"}
var gaugeConfig4 = { "canvasHolderId": "BT", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#F1C40F", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "8"}
var gaugeConfig5 = { "canvasHolderId": "XML", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#F39C12", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "7.5"}
var gaugeConfig6 = { "canvasHolderId": "JAVA", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#E67E22", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "9"}
var gaugeConfig7 = { "canvasHolderId": "MVC", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#E67E22", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "8.5"}
var gaugeConfig8 = { "canvasHolderId": "SP", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#D35400", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "6.5"}
var gaugeConfig9 = { "canvasHolderId": "WB", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#E74C3C", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "7"}
var gaugeConfig10 = { "canvasHolderId": "SQL", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#E74C3C", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "8"}
var gaugeConfig11 = { "canvasHolderId": "HB", "width": "150", "height": "150", "circleColor": "#222", "arcColor": "#C0392B", "canvasFillColor": "#333", "textPosition": "inside" , "skillLevel" : "6.5"}

            function drawGauge(gc) {

                var W = gc.width;
                var H = gc.height;
                var degrees = 0;
                var new_degrees = 0;
                var difference = 0;
                var color = gc.arcColor;
                var bgcolor = gc.circleColor;
                var text = gc.skillLevel;
                var animation_loop, redraw_loop;
                var me = this;
                var canvasHolder = document.getElementById(gc.canvasHolderId);
                var canvasCreator = document.createElement("canvas");

                canvasCreator.id = _randomId();
                canvasCreator.width = gc.width;
                canvasCreator.height = gc.height;
                canvasHolder.appendChild(canvasCreator);
                var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasCreator.id);


                function _randomId() {
                    var d = new Date();
                    return "canvas" + d.getFullYear() + "" + d.getMonth() + "" + d.getDay() + "" + d.getHours() + "" + d.getSeconds() + "" + d.getMilliseconds()*Math.random();
                }

                function _init() {                        

                    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");                        
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);    

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
                    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
                    ctx.arc(W / 2, H / 2, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); //you can see the arc now
                    ctx.stroke();

                    var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
                    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
                    ctx.arc(W / 2, H / 2, 50, 0 - 90 * Math.PI / 180, radians - 90 * Math.PI / 180, false);

                    ctx.stroke();


                    ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    ctx.font = "30px bebas";
                    text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
                    ctx.fillText(text, W / 2 - text_width / 2, H / 2 + 12);
                }

                function _animate_to() {                        
                    if (degrees == new_degrees)
                        clearInterval(animation_loop);    
                    if (degrees < new_degrees)
                        degrees++;
                    else
                        degrees--;    
                    _init();
                }

                function _draw() {

                    if (typeof animation_loop != undefined) clearInterval(animation_loop);

                    new_degrees = Math.round((text * 3600)/100);
                    difference = new_degrees - degrees;

                    animation_loop = setInterval(function () { _animate_to() }, 1000 / difference);

                }

                _draw();
            }

           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig1);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig2);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig3);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig4);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig5);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig6);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig7);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig8);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig9);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig10);
           new drawGauge(gaugeConfig11);
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="HTML" class="skills"></div>
<div id="CSS" class="skills"></div>
<div id="JS" class="skills"></div>
<div id="JQ" class="skills"></div>
<div id="BT" class="skills"></div>
<div id="XML" class="skills"></div>
<div id="JAVA" class="skills"></div>
<div id="MVC" class="skills"></div>
<div id="SP" class="skills"></div>
<div id="WB" class="skills"></div>
<div id="SQL" class="skills"></div>
<div id="HB" class="skills"></div>
```

Comment: so you're saying it only works when not run within $(document).ready?  What happens instead?  Are you looking in your error console?  What debugging are you doing?

Comment: Are you sure you have a DOM element with `id="skills"` that's not being injected into the DOM after the ready event?

Comment: It only works when I don't have the first two lines of code, meaning just plain javascript, no jquery.
I do have DOM element with id-'skills'. I am loading this script after the element but since document ready is there it should not be a problem for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other possibilities but most likely one of two things (or the combination of both) is preventing this.

1. You have multiple elements with the ID of `#skills` which should actually be a class instead of ID
2. `#skills` isn't available to jQuery when loading so you can try fixing that by replacing `$('#skills').click(function() { ... })` with `$(document).on('click', '#skills', function() { ... });`

### [Visualize the madness](http://jsfiddle.net/QStGJ/)

Comment: It tried to include class everywhere instead of one id. It's not working even in the line of code you specified.

Comment: So you replaced your HTML from `id="skills"` to `class="skills"` AND you changed the Javascript from `#skills` to `.skills` ?

Comment: Replaced the id with class="gauge" everywhere I need the gauge to appear. in the function I replaced it with .guage, also tried with gauge but doesn't work.

Comment: Update your original code with whatever is most current now from your changes and add your HTML

Comment: change `$(document).on('click', 'skills' ...` to `...('click', '.skills' ... ` need the period before `skills` to work

Comment: Once I edited your code to have the correct selector, it works.  And you don't need to delegate (aka you can use `$('.skills').on('click'...` instead of `$(document).on('click', '.skills'...`) View here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/QStGJ/

Comment: Fixed it!. The problem was that initially the div did not had any width and height, hence there was no place to click. I was just clicking outside of that div. Now I would like to know how to make it draw only once, meaning once I click it will draw and after that no matter how many type I click it won't draw. Can i achieve the same effect with scroll property of jquery?

Comment: Yes.  I'll update my fiddle and put comments where the changes are for you to see:  http://jsfiddle.net/tvEC5/

Comment: Now be aware:  that update will stop clicks from ANY button/div after the first click, not just the one that was clicked.  If you want it to only disable the one that is clicked, let me know and I can show you that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying to achieve the same thing with scroll functionality. What I want to do is that once the div is clicked or either the page is scrolled to that div, it will animate once and will not animate after that. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I think what we can do is set both the skillsClicked and skillsScrolled to true inside the click function whenever the div is either scrolled or clicked.

Comment: Hi Deryck can you help me fix this one? Also I just want to disable the one that is clicked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(document).on('click', 'skills', function()
```

You need

```
$(document).on('click', '.skills', function()
```